# Cannot push docker image to private registry - cert error

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, docker

I am trying to setup private docker registry. I have installed it on some on premise server and made sure it's available at some domain, for explanation purpose let's assume it's `hub.mydomain.com`. It has a self signed certificate so without any adjustments I would expect a failure when trying to push an image.

So now, I tagged an image with `docker image tag traefik:latest hub.mydomain.com/traefik`

And when I try to push it I get following:

```
$ docker image push hub.mydomain.com/traefik
The push refers to repository [hub.mydomain.com/traefik]
Get https://hub.mydomain.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

So far so good - I expected that. To avoid problems with certificates I wanted to consider this registry as unsecure so I created `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file with contents:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["hub.mydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

I restarted docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` and checked `docker system info` to verify that the registry is insecure:

```
docker system info
Containers: 15
...
Insecure Registries:
 hub.mydomain.com:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Now, when I have the registry in unsecured I would expect that certificate signature error should be ignore but when I try to push it I still get:

```
docker image push hub.mydomain.com/traefik
The push refers to repository [hub.mydomain.com/traefik]
Get https://hub.mydomain.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

How can I ignore this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. is there any workaround?